# Bike Rim spokes with array modifier are not centered

Tags: modifiers

So I am trying to model a simple bike and I am struggling with the spokes. I put a Cylinder in and put the §D cursor and the Origin on the axle (Which is already alligned with my tire and outside part of my rim). Then I added an empty object which I use for my array modifier. Then i applied the array modifier with the empty object as object Offset and rotate the empty object. First I thought i got it but looking from the side you can see the spokes are not centered.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Setting Relative Offset to 0 was the solution